# How to kill a npm child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, kill, child-process

I've a `package.json` on which I define a `debug` script. This script launches a `node` app.

The whole `npm` script is being launched by a test, and this last one must kill the `debug` script once the test ends.

So when I `spawn` `npm run debug` and I kill it, the `node` process isn't killed.

I've tried to either kill the whole process with `child_process.kill` and spawning a `kill` bash command with no luck since the `pid` doesn't belong to the `node` launched using `npm run debug`.

How  to kill that `node` process for which I don't own its `pid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to necessarily own the PID to be able to kill it (as long as the user running the scripts has permission to do it).

You could spawn commands and do it like you would in command-line (of which there are a number of ways). There are also packages like `find-process` which you can use to find the process that way as well.

An even easier way is to write some file that has the pid in it when `debug` starts up (if you can). Then you can just read that file back in to get the PID.

```
// in debug
import { writeFile } from 'fs';

writeFile('debug.pid', process.pid, 'utf8', err => err && console.log('Error writing pid file'));

// in app where it'll kill
import { readFile } from 'fs';

let debugPid;
readFile('debug.pid', 'utf8', (err, data) => err ? console.log('Error reading pid file') : debugPid = data);
```

Regardless of approach, once you have the PID, use `process.kill()` to kill it:

```
process.kill(pid);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the effort! Will you add a reference to [Terminate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminate) package? I used it as some answerer suggested (but the answer is deleted).

Comment: It was probably deleted because it's generally not advised to recommend specific libraries or packages (since that's opinionated). I'm already skirting that rule by mentioning `find-process` as an example of packages that find a process ID.

Comment: I mean that since finally I solved my issue with `Terminate`, you could suggest it in your own answer. Why not?

Comment: Terminate just uses `process.kill()` under the hood, it just wraps it up in a way that you don't have to think about handling errors and what not yourself (with process.on() and the like). While it's cool that you used it to solve your problem, just saying "use terminate" doesn't really teach anything.

Comment: Again, you just need to add a reference to that package so future readers will be able to get it if they need to. You could explain in your answer what you've said in your last comment :D